# Calling onClick inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a custom Input Box and when I type inside a custom input component It'll re-render the typed input inside.

```
import {
  Badge,
  Box,
  CloseButton,
  Grid,
  GridItem,
  Input,
  Text
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function InputTag(props) {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState(props.values);

  const removeTag = (index) => {
    setTags(tags.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const addTag = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value !== "") {
      setTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
      props.setFieldValue("tags", [...tags, event.target.value]);
      event.target.value = "";
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.show === false && setTags([]);
  }, [props.show]);

//update values based on click suggestions
  useEffect(() => {
    setTags([props.values, props.suggTag]);
  }, [props.suggTag, props.values]);

  return (
    <Box
      display={"flex"}
      border="1px"
      borderColor={"gray.200"}
      borderRadius={"md"}
      padding={2}
    >
      <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={2} overflow="visible">
        {tags &&
          tags.map((tag, index) => (
            <GridItem key={index}>
              <Badge
                variant="solid"
                colorScheme={"purple"}
                display={"flex"}
                borderRadius="full"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
                gap={2}
              >
                <Text>{tag}</Text>
                <CloseButton onClick={() => removeTag(index)} />
              </Badge>
            </GridItem>
          ))}
      </Grid>
      <Input
        type="text"
        name="tags"
        id="tags"
        variant={"unstyled"}
        placeholder="Add Tag"
        _placeholder={{ fontsize: "md" }}
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        onBlur={props.handleBlur}
        onError={props.errors}
        onKeyUp={(event) =>
          event.key === "Enter" ? addTag(event) && event.preventDefault() : null
        }
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default InputTag;
```

Here, when I hit enter It'll render them inside the custom Input Box

I Inserted a custom array of strings as "ex_Tag" inside `Previewer.js` so that when I click on the word in array, it'll also get rendered inside custom input as well.

```
function NewUploader({ isOpen, onClose }) {
  const cancelRef = useRef();
  const ex_tags = ["Design", "Strategy", "Human Centered Design"];
  const [show, Setshow] = useState(true);
  const [suggTag, setSuggTag] = useState();

  const initialValues = {
    files: null,
    tags: []
  };
  const validationSchema = yup.object({
    files: yup.mixed().required("File is Required"),
    tags: yup.mixed().required("tags required")
  });
  const onSubmit = (values, actions) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("files", values.files[0]);
    formData.append("tags", values.tags);

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ", " + pair[1]);
    }
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    actions.resetForm();
    Setshow(!show);
    onClose();
  };

  const handlethis = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
//insert suggested word to useState so i can pass it to custom input
  const handleClick = (tag) => {
    setSuggTag(tag);
  };

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} isCentered>
      {/* update code on model here */}
      <ModalOverlay />
      <ModalContent>
        <ModalHeader>
          <Text fontWeight={"bold"} color="gray.900">
            Upload Buddy
          </Text>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalCloseButton />
        <ModalBody>
          <Flex direction="column" gap={3}>
            <Box>
              <Text fontWeight={"normal"} color="gray.700">
                This learning contentwill not be summarised. to summarize your
                content, use{" "}
                <Link color={"purple.400"}>Create Knowledge Nugget</Link> option
                instead.
              </Text>
            </Box>
            <Box>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
              >
                {(formik) => (
                  <Form
                    onSubmit={handlethis}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    encType="multipart/form-data"
                  >
                    <FormLabel htmlFor="file">
                      <Text
                        fontSize="sm"
                        fontWeight="normal"
                        color="gray.900"
                        fontFamily={"body"}
                      >
                        Upload files
                      </Text>
                    </FormLabel>
                    {/* drag droop sec */}
                    {formik.isSubmitting ? (
                      <>
                        <Grid
                          templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)"
                          gap={2}
                          overflow="hidden"
                        >
                          {formik.values.files &&
                            formik.values.files.map((file, index) => (
                              <GridItem key={index}>
                                <Badge
                                  variant="solid"
                                  borderRadius="xl"
                                  colorScheme={"gray"}
                                  w={file.name.length * 4}
                                  h="8"
                                  display="flex"
                                  justifyContent="center"
                                  alignItems="center"
                                  my={2}
                                >
                                  <Text fontFamily={"body"}>{file.name}</Text>
                                  <CloseButton colorScheme={"blackAlpha"} />
                                </Badge>
                              </GridItem>
                            ))}
                        </Grid>
                        <Progress colorScheme={"yellow"} isIndeterminate />
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        <Dragdrop setFieldValue={formik.setFieldValue} />

                        <Grid
                          templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)"
                          gap={2}
                          overflow="hidden"
                        >
                          {formik.values.files &&
                            formik.values.files.map((file, index) => (
                              <GridItem key={index}>
                                <Badge
                                  variant="solid"
                                  borderRadius="xl"
                                  colorScheme={"gray"}
                                  w={file.name.length * 4}
                                  h="8"
                                  display="flex"
                                  justifyContent="space-between"
                                  alignItems="center"
                                  my={2}
                                >
                                  <Text fontFamily={"body"}>{file.name}</Text>
                                  <CloseButton colorScheme={"blackAlpha"} />
                                </Badge>
                              </GridItem>
                            ))}
                        </Grid>
                        {formik.errors.files && formik.touched.files && (
                          <Text fontFamily={"body"} color="red">
                            {formik.errors.files}
                          </Text>
                        )}
                      </>
                    )}

                    <FormErrorMessage>
                      <ErrorMessage name="file" />
                    </FormErrorMessage>

                    <FormLabel htmlFor="tags">
                      <Text
                        fontSize="sm"
                        fontWeight="normal"
                        color="gray.900"
                        fontFamily={"body"}
                      >
                        Tags
                      </Text>
                    </FormLabel>
                    <InputTag
                      setFieldValue={formik.setFieldValue}
                      handleChange={formik.handleChange}
                      handleBlur={formik.handleBlur.call}
                      values={formik.values.tags}
                      show={show}
                      suggTag={suggTag}
                    />

                    {formik.errors.tags && formik.touched.tags && (
                      <Text fontFamily={"body"} color="red">
                        {formik.errors.tags}
                      </Text>
                    )}
                    <FormErrorMessage>
                      <ErrorMessage name="tags" />
                    </FormErrorMessage>

                    <Box
                      aria-invalid="true"
                      display={"flex"}
                      flexDir="row"
                      gap={2}
                      my={2}
                    >
                      <Text fontFamily={"body"}>Suggested</Text>

                      <Grid
                        templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)"
                        gap={2}
                        overflow="hidden"
                      >
                        {ex_tags.map(
                          (tag, index) => (
                            <GridItem key={index}>
//I inserted on click call here
                              <Box onClick={handleClick(tag)}>
                                <Badge
                                  variant={"subtle"}
                                  borderRadius="lg"
                                  colorScheme={"gray"}
                                  _hover={{
                                    cursor: "pointer",
                                    bgColor: "gray.200"
                                  }}
                                >
                                  <Text fontFamily={"body"}>{tag}</Text>
                                </Badge>
                              </Box>
                            </GridItem>
                          ),
                          this
                        )}
                      </Grid>
                    </Box>

                    <Box display={"flex"} justifyContent="center" my={3}>
                      <Button
                        type="button"
                        ref={cancelRef}
                        colorScheme="yellow"
                        isLoading={formik.isSubmitting}
                        onClick={formik.handleSubmit}
                      >
                        <Text
                          fontWeight="bold"
                          fontSize="18px"
                          color="gray.900"
                          fontFamily={"body"}
                        >
                          Submit
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </Box>
                  </Form>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </Box>
          </Flex>
        </ModalBody>
      </ModalContent>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default NewUploader;
```

but It seems when I render them to the screen it will come out as I triggered the onClick even though I didn't.

For now I commented out the useEffect func inside input component

I have uploaded it to code sandbox Bellow.
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-heyrovsky-9kr0ex?file=/src/Previewer.js

Comment: May I understand why this: `autoComplete="off"`? Seems like you need auto-complete with a customized list/array of values to be shown - is that correct? May be you could find some reference to use from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chakra-ui-autocomplete): https://www.npmjs.com/package/chakra-ui-autocomplete.

Comment: Thank you for responce @jsN00b, Inside the Form I set "autoComplete=off" since it suggested previously inserted values, The issue arises when I tried to insert the suggested value using onClick, May I update the question with more details

Comment: My previous comment was in reference to the file: `custInput.js`, specifically at line 72.

Comment: Thank you, Yes it's for suggesting values based on previous inputs

Comment: I updated the question above with more details, Thanks